# Set PlacementTarget of ContextMenu opening via keyboard WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

I can's set `PlacementTarget` for `ContextMenu`. It is always opened (via Shift+F10) in the center of listbox.

I tried:

```
private void listBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift && 
      (e.Key == Key.F10 || e.SystemKey == Key.F10)){
       var listBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
       listBox.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
  }
}
```

and

```
private void listBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
   var listBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
   listBox.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
}
```

But it still doesn't work as expected. (I expect it is shown in the center of selected itemlistbox)

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you tell more exactly what's wrong? any exception? or simply the ContextMenu is still shown at center?

Comment: still shown at center of listbox, but i expect at center of selected listboxitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your code. The problem is you cannot change the `PlacementTarget` of the  the `ContextMenu` once it is set to the `ListBox`. That means the `ListBox` is always set as `PlacementTarget` of the ContextMenu. I understand that that ContextMenu is in fact used for the selected item. So why not set it for each item? Then it works expectedly. Try this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="some_source_here"/>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <!-- your ContextMenu here -->
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>            
</ListBox>
```

There is not any code behind involved here. Just change your XAML like above.

Comment: yes, thanks. it will work :) but i'd like to have the same behavior without rewriting my contextmenu. All bindings will not work and i will have to rewrite it :( Hope there is other solution

Comment: @maskalek I think there is just a little change to make the Binding work. Could you give some example of the Binding you set on the ContextMenu?